# refer a working video editor

Tags: video-editor

I need a simple video editor, just pasting several video files in mov format and producing mp4. tried openshot and pitivi and they keep crashing and cannot produce anything. quite pathetic.

Answer (score 1):

Try Kdenlive (http://www.kdenlive.org/) . It's on the Ubuntu Software Center. Works well on many formats, including the ones you wish to use (.mov and .mp4) and it's quite simple to use.

Answer (score 0):

Since OpenShot does not work for you, you could try Avidemux, which has a simple interface and is lightweight. If that does not work for you, you could take a look at this site:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/top5-linux-video-editing-system-software/

Which lists Avidemux as well as 4 other editing programs you can try. Though I would suggest trying Avid first as it seems most like what you are aiming at.