# What are the alternatives to Camtasia Studio to edit videos on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, video, video-editor

For Windows 7 there is a program called *Camastia Studio*, which I use to edit videos. I need to edit videos on Ubuntu, so I tried to download Camastia and install it via wine, but it doesn't work. What alternatives do I have for editing videos on Ubuntu?

**The suggested software should at least include the following options**:

1. cutting video
2. adding text to the video
3. zoom while the video is playing
4. transitions should be available

Comment: Possible dups: http://askubuntu.com/questions/5911/video-editing-software-options, http://askubuntu.com/questions/317559/refer-a-working-video-editor, http://askubuntu.com/questions/12611/application-for-slicing-video

Comment: Take a look at this[Post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/328336/is-there-any-screen-recorder-with-zoom-functionality/328382#328382), it might be of help.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the program "Openshot". Install it from the Softwarecenter. It is quite good for 1 and 4. Point 3, I don't know. Point 2, there is a title function in Openshot. Or alternatively, there are different subtitle tools, as gnome-subtitles, which could do the job.

Comment: i tried Openshot i heard about it an i used it it's that good it's not like camastia i mean it can't write inside the video or fastforword the video or i just need to know how to use it i don't know actually so please give advice's i think u i'll help thanx for your answer by the way

Comment: As I see now, Camtasia is a tool for creating video tutorials. If you are searching for something like this you might try Kazam (Softwarecenter). Kazam makes Desktop videos, you can also record microphone and speakers. Zoom might be done by KMag, which is a screen magnifier, which is not very good. Other option for this would be the Compiz magnifier. But I couldn't make the shortcuts work, it seems that Unity disables them. Install compiz and compizconfig-settings-manager to try it out. You will have to add text, using OpenShot, or Kdenlive, which has more features.

Answer (score 0):

### How about [Kdenlive](http://kdenlive.org/)

> Kdenlive - a free and open-source video editor for GNU/Linux and FreeBSD
>
> Kdenlive is an intuitive and powerful multi-track video editor, including most recent video technologies. Our software is completely free, as defined by the GNU foundation. Using Kdenlive is investing in a community driven project, which aims to establish relationships between people in order to built the best video tools.
>
> Latest version is Kdenlive 0.9.6, released in april 2013, see [announcement](http://www.kdenlive.org/users/j-b-m/kdenlive-096-released) and [info page](http://www.kdenlive.org/discover/0.9.6).

[image]

**Some of the features**: - (full listing [here](http://kdenlive.org/features))

- Multitrack edition with a timeline and unlimited number of video and audio tracks.
- Video and audio tracks organized in layers.
- Tools to create, move, crop and delete video clips, audio clips, text clips and image clips.
- Configurable keyboard shortcuts and interface layouts.
- A wide range of effects and transitions. Ability to add custom effects and transitions.
- Non-blocking rendering using a rendering separate application. Stop, pause and restart rendering. Continue to work on your project without any possible loss of data.
- Export to standard formats:

  1. DV (PAL and NTSC).
  2. Mpeg2 (PAL, NTSC and HDV) and AVCHD (HDV).
  3. High quality h264.
  4. Non-destructive formats.

Also the [Kdenlive Manual](http://userbase.kde.org/Kdenlive/Manual) might be of interest to you.

---

**Installation**:

- Please refer to their HP, section: [Download](http://kdenlive.org/download-ubuntu) for detailed information
- or use Ubuntu Software-Center.
- Alternatively you can do all the process typing the following command line in a terminal :

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sunab/kdenlive-release && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install kdenlive